# OpenXML, bug in SDK?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

EDIT :

As I explain in this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282732/how-to-fix-a-corrupted-zip-file, I think the program corrupted the zip metadata.

Do you have any idea why and how to fix it ?

---

I was following this link : http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/03/28/132189.aspx when I found a very weird bug.

Once the program is ended, if I try to open the docx, Word tells me the file is corrupted. Actually, the docx is not corrupted. It is the embedded spreadsheet which is corrupted.

The file that causes this is sheet1.xml. Except the data changes, the program also changes the namespace. But the file is correct.

If you extract the spreadsheet from the docx, then extract the file sheet1.xml from the spreadsheet and finally inject back the file into the spreadsheet and the spreadsheet into the docx, the file is not corrupted anymore.

I just extract the sheet1.xml, nothing more with it. I don't understand what's happening ... May be one of you will have an explanation.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you suspect it's a bug, post it on the bug tracker.

Comment: I have no idea if it is a bug. If you find the Microsoft OpenXml bug tracker, let me know ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it. Not the better way but without any better solution, I share it with you:

First of all: Open the Word document and find the chart. Once the chart found, retrieve the name of the linked spreadsheet:

```
xlsx = chartPart.EmbeddedPackagePart.Uri.OriginalString;
```

Then, extract the spreadsheet from the Word document (I used the .NET 4.5 [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API) :

```
using (var archivePPT = ZipFile.Open("Template3.docx", ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    var entry = archivePPT.GetEntry(xlsx.Remove(0,1));
    entry.ExtractToFile("c:\\tmp\\" + xlsx.Split('/').Last());
}
```

Then, I edit the extracted spreadsheet data and the word cached data as explain in the blog post.

Finally, I added back the spreadsheet into the word document:

```
using (var archivePPT = ZipFile.Open("Test3.docx", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    archivePPT.GetEntry(xlsx.Remove(0, 1)).Delete();
    archivePPT.CreateEntryFromFile("c:\\tmp\\" + xlsx.Split('/').Last(), xlsx.Remove(0,1));
}
```